# How to construct a tree structure with smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Here is a code snippet which i want to get a tree structure with smart pointer.But i got c3646('parent': unknown override specifier) and c4430(missing type specifier - int assumed) in vs.Does anybody know what's going on and how do i fix it>?

```
#include<memory>

class Obj {
    ObjPtr parent;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> ObjPtr;
```

Comment: You should include the header file which includes the interface of``ObjPtr ``

Comment: @Asesh I've already defined it below the class.typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> ObjPtr;

Comment: Use `ObjPtr` after the `typedef`, not the other way around. Besides, why a tree structure would have a `shared_ptr` are you planning to share node between different trees?

Comment: @alfC And as you use `ObjPtr` *within* the class, typedef is better placed in front of the class, I suppose?

Comment: @alfC So there is no way to get a tree structure with smart pointer?The shared_ptr can alter to unique_ptr but it still can not work.

Comment: Yes, `unique_ptr` seems a more sane option to start. If you need a `shared_ptr` you can change to it later. Yes, a tree can be implemented with a smart pointers. Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Obj{
    public:
    using ObjPtr = std::shared_ptr<Obj>;
    private:
    ObjPtr parent;
};
```

doesn't need so many declarations.

Comment: Just to clarify, with this approach `ObjPtr` will not be available outside `class Obj`.

Comment: @cantordust ok, fixed that.

Answer (score 9):

Your `Obj` class doesn't know what an `ObjPtr` is because you provide the typedef *after* `Obj`. You need to place it above the class definition and provide a forward declaration of `Obj`:

```
class Obj; // Forward declaration

typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> ObjPtr; // Now ObjPtr knows about class Obj

class Obj {
    ObjPtr parent; // We can now use ObjPtr
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a typedef *at all*

```
class Obj{
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> parent;
};
```

But a tree only needs owning pointers in the parent -> child direction. You can use a raw pointer in the child -> parent direction

```
struct Node {
    Node * parent;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
};
```

Comment: Whether children own their parents, or parents own their children, depends only on who needs whom to stay alive. In the `git` commit DAG, for instance, it's the children that keep their parents alive, yet in the `git` directory trees, it's the parents that keep their children alive... (`git` just being an example here). The only important thing is, that you don't construct cycles with your smart pointers.

Comment: Of course, you may argue that an object with just a parent pointer is nothing but a linked list that may happen to share a tail with some other linked list of the same type. However, once you register the children with their parent (using plain pointers), you are firmly in tree territory.

Comment: @cmaster yes, `shared_ptr` is more appropriate for a general DAG.